# Shear transformation and relation above/below in TrapezoidalMap

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I'm currently reading about point location trapezoidal structure. And i stumbled upon this shearing part. I believe that if we have segment $s$ with endpoints $p_1 = (x_1+\epsilon y_1,y_1), p_2 = (x_2+\epsilon y_2,y_2)$ and point to check $q=(x+\epsilon y, y)$ with $x_1 < x < x_2.$ Then after shearing if y is relatively big we can have $x_2+\epsilon y_2 < x + \epsilon y,$ which is probably not that we want.

In words, point to check can be sheared right beyound the right endpoint of its underlying segment. And check with vertical line will fail.

[image: slide]

EDIT:
The question is, that if point will be sheared to far to the right and so it will jump from the left side of vertical line through the right endpoint of the underlying segment to the right side?

[image]

EDIT2:
**question:** If due to the shear point jumps over the vertical then comparison with this line to see if the point is above or below the segment will give wrong result, not the same as before shear. Have i missed something in the algorithm?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Updated

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: @NaN question added.

Comment: I find your English difficult to understand. Why are you trying to apply a "large" shear when your own image says to choose a **sufficiently small** $\epsilon$?

Comment: @JessicaK , just to make image more demonstrative. Jump can happen even with small $\epsilon.$